# Getting 0 rows while querying external table in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We created the schema as follows:

```
create external schema spectrum
from data catalog
database 'test'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::20XXXXXXXXXXX:role/athenaaccess'
create external database if not exists;
```

and table as follows:

```
create external table spectrum.Customer(
Subr_Id integer,
SUB_CURRENTSTATUS varchar(100),
AIN integer,
ACCOUNT_CREATED timestamp,
Subr_Name varchar(100),
LAST_DEACTIVATED timestamp)
partitioned by (LAST_ACTIVATION timestamp)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://cequity-redshiftspectrum-test/'
table properties ('numRows'='1000');
```

the access rights are as follows:

Roles of athenaQuickSight access, Full Athena access, and s3 full access are attached to the redshift cluster

However, when we query as below we are getting 0 records. please help.

```
select count(*) from spectrum.Customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your query returns zero rows from a partitioned external table, check whether a partition has been added to this external table. Redshift Spectrum only scans files in an Amazon S3 location that has been explicitly added using ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION. Query the [SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS.html) view to finding existing partitions. Run ALTER TABLE ADD … PARTITION for each missing partition.

[Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-troubleshooting.html#spectrum-troubleshooting-no-rows-partitioned-table)

I had the same issue. Doing the above, resolved my issue.

P.S. Explicit run of ALTER TABLE command to create partition can also be automated.

Comment: Great works well. But how can you keep on adding new partitions to the same table in an automated way?

Comment: Please follow this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184577/redshift-spectrum-automatically-partition-tables-by-date-folder/47217546#47217546